# Generalize http:outbound-gateway reply-channel

Tags: spring-integration

Given a gateway that handles service calls to a ws. My goal is to supply the `http:outbound-gateway's reply-channel` using `header-enricher` since I'll be adding multiple methods to `gateway` and I would like to make use of only 1 `http:outbound-gateway`

I can currently receive the response up to groovy script (2) BUT it doesn't seem to want to return the results to the actual method that calls the service

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<gateway id="registryService" service-interface="RegistryService">
<method name="create" request-channel="create-request-channel"
        reply-channel="create-reply-channel" />
</gateway>

<chain input-channel="create-request-channel" output-channel="create-request-fulfillment-channel">
 <transformer>
   // groovy script that contains the method to be called in the ws (1)
 </transformer>
 <object-to-json-transformer/>
 <header-enricher>
   <reply-channel overwrite="true" ref="create-reply-fulfillment-channel" />
 </header-enricher>
</chain>

<http:outbound-gateway request-channel="create-request-fulfillment-channel"
                       extract-request-payload="true"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                       url="http://localhost:4567" http-method="POST" />

<chain input-channel="create-reply-fulfillment-channel"
       output-channel="create-reply-channel">
       <json-to-object-transformer type="JsonRpcResponse"/>
       <transformer>
           //groovy script to manipulate response (2)
       </transformer>
</chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

Each method of your gateway should enrich message with some unique 'routing' header value:

```
<gateway id="registryService" service-interface="RegistryService">
  <method name="create" request-channel="http-request-channel"
        reply-channel="registryService-create-responseChannel">
    <header name="routingHeader" value="registryService-create" />
  </method>
</gateway>
```

And then send message straight forward to outbound gateway:

```
<http:outbound-gateway request-channel="http-request-channel"
                       response-channel="http-response-channel"
                       extract-request-payload="true"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                       url="http://localhost:4567" http-method="POST" />
```

Http outbound gateway sends request to the remote server and then forward response to `http-response-channel`. To this channel is attached header value router, which basis on the value of routing header, sends (routes) message to the appropriate channel:

```
<header-value-router input-channel="http-response-channel" header-name="routingHeader">
  <mapping value="registryService-create" channel="registryService-create-responseChannel" />
  <mapping value="someOtherService-otherMethod" channel="someOtherService-otherMethod-responseChannel" />
</header-value-router>
```

Of course you don't need to send it back directly to the gateway - you can add some additional processing between those components, and all the time you can route message basis on the header value.

It's simpler than hacks with groovy and I use it myself - proven that works ;)